# Puppet module generate - the action of generate does not exist in puppet module command

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Puppet version 7.26 (Open sourece)
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

I cannot create my own module by command:

```
puppet module generate <module_name>
```

Get error as below:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I also check the module command by 'puppet module --help' and I could not find the generate action:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Is there any alternative way to generate your own puppet module? Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwqQi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Doj.png

Answer (score 0):

> Puppet module generate - the action of generate does not exist in puppet module command

Yes, the `generate` action is no longer supported by `puppet module`.  That command is now better focused, as a module management tool only.

Behavior comparable to that that used to be available from `puppet module generate` is now available from [the Puppet Development Kit](https://www.puppet.com/docs/pdk/3.x/pdk.html) (PDK) as `pdk new module <modname>`.

If you have configured the Puppet platform repository on your CentOS 7 system then you should be able to get PDK via `sudo yum install pdk`.